# Getting results of dropdown lists

Tags: django, dropdown

im a beginner in using Django. I need to create a Game for my University project.

I have some different questions, which have always 4 different answers. The answers will once have different values for the player, but im not that far, yet.

I did this in a dropdown list:

class Player(BasePlayer):

```
Antwort1 = models.IntegerField(
choices=[
    [1, 'Mitfahrgelegenheit'],
    [2, 'BlaBlaCar'],
    [3, 'FlixBus'],
    [4, 'Mitfahrzentrale'],
    [5, ' ']
    ], default=5)

Antwort2 = models.IntegerField(
    choices=[
        [1, 'Mitfahrgelegenheit'],
        [2, 'BlaBlaCar'],
        [3, 'FlixBus'],
        [4, 'Mitfahrzentrale'],
        [5, ' ']
    ], default=5)

Antwort3 = models.IntegerField(
    choices=[
        [1, 'Mitfahrgelegenheit'],
        [2, 'BlaBlaCar'],
        [3, 'FlixBus'],
        [4, 'Mitfahrzentrale'],
        [5, ' ']
    ], default=5)
```

and so on...

How can I get the results out of the choices? 
If I put {{% form.answer1 %}} in my result page, the result in fact is the answer, but shown as a drop down list.

thanks for your help and best whises,

Julian

Comment: can you give a little explanation of how you need it? means what you want to show, we are not clear about what you want to display, can you give an example?

Comment: I want to show, how the user has answered on the different questions. For example: you drive from xxx to xxx and you have 4 possibilities to go with: To make it easier: by bus, by train, by bike, by car.                                        i have 12 questions on the distance so the answers will differ. in the end i want to show how often the user went by bike, by car, etc.

Comment: Now you are getting 1 2 like this in your template right? But you want to show blablacar etc like that?

Comment: What I did in my Resultspage is {{ form.answer1 }}, that shows me the answer on the question in the choice page. But actually it shows me the result again in a dropdown list. I want to have a table with the summary of answers on each: so 3x blablacar, 2x Flixbus, 3xmitfahrzentrale etc...

Comment: but the result will come from database, its displaying a dropdown because you are using the form to display it

Comment: Oke. But are the answers the user gives in the Database? How do I Show the Database?       Thanks for ur help

Comment: go thorough how to get values from database in django and see the ways